# How to identify if a JSON Object is nested or not

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am getting a JSON object on javascript page from a JSP page through an ajax call. I want to find out if it is a nested JSON object or not.
For example:
A simple JSON Object looks like this:

```
{
    "time":"2015-04-23T06:23:48.173+0000",
    "timeZone":"IST"
}
```

and a nested JSON Object looks like this:

```
{
    data" : {
        "attributes" : {
            "key1":"abc",
            "key2":"xyz"
        }
    }
}
```

So I want to differentiate between the two as I want to work with them differently
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Iterate over the properties of the object. If any property value is an object, it's nested.

Comment: Loop through all the properties and check if any of them are objects themselves?

Comment: I don't want to come across rude, but a quick Google search and read of how JSON is read would have given you your answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you parsed the JSON, iterate over the properties of the object and check whether any property value is an object or not:

```
var isNested = Object.keys(obj).some(function(key) {
    return obj[key] && typeof obj[key] === 'object';
});
```

Comment: The thing is every json object itself can be further nested, so checking further nested keys will be a cumbersome process. I was wondering if there was a way to differentiate between nested json object and simple json? hope I have cleared myself.

Comment: Why do you need to test any other objects? Nested is nested, whether it's one level or ten. The above code tells you whether an object is nested or not.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. One last question: Is there any way to determine if a JSON Object is nested or simple if we do not know anything about the key value pairs of the JSON Object coming from back end?

Comment: That's exactly what my answer is doing.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript objects, are contained inside the curly brackets **{ }**. A nested object is where the value of a key is another object.

In your example, the "attributes" object holds key1 and key2. Which is then nested inside the "data" object as its value.

JSON is mostly the same as regular javascript objects with a few restrictions and syntax.

Comment: May have misunderstood the question; wasn't sure if you were asking about nested JSON objects, or for code-snippet on how to iterate for them. Regardless, seems like both are covered in the answers. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function, which checks for any object defined after the first level:

```
function check_if_nested(obj) {
    check_nest=[]
    obj.map(function(e,i) {$.each(e, function(v){
      if(typeof(obj[0][v])=='object') {check_nest.push('nested')} else {check_nest.push('not nested')}
    })})
    if(check_nest.includes('nested')) {return(true)} else {return(false)}
    }
```

Usage:

**Not nested example**:

```
obj_1 = [{
    one: "apples",
    two: "oranges"
}]
```

..usage:

```
check_if_nested(obj_1)
```

false

**Nested example**:

```
obj_2 = [{
    one: "apples",
    two: "oranges",
    children: [{
        three: "bananas",
        four: "jicamas"
    }]
}]
```

..usage:

```
check_if_nested(obj_2)
```

true